# How do I suggest a change to the HTTP standard?

Tags: http, standards, rfc

I have a fairly simple addition to the HTTP standard.  An ambitious goal I know, but I'd at least like to submit a proposal and get feedback on the idea.  What is the proper forum/method of doing so?

Comment: Why not post your idea here anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current HTTP standard falls under the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) working group Hypertext Transfer Protocol Bis ([httpbis](http://www.ietf.org/html.charters/httpbis-charter.html)). The page there shows the contact information for the group and the current modifications/clarifications to the [RFC-2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) standard that defines HTTP and the proposed changes, etc. It is an active group, so give it a whirl!!

Answer (score 9):

According to W3C's [HTTP page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/):

> Now that both HTTP extensions and
>   HTTP/1.1 are stable specifications,
>   W3C has closed the HTTP Activity. The
>   Activity has achieved its goals of
>   creating a successful standard that
>   addresses the weaknesses of earlier
>   HTTP versions.
>
> An effort to revise HTTP/1.1 started
>   in the [IETF httpbis Working Group](http://www.ietf.org/html.charters/httpbis-charter.html)

The page from the latter link has a mailing list you can join, as well as the scope of the working group. You may well be able to get feedback about the merit of your idea in the abstract, but certainly don't get your hopes up at effecting change.